# Using Find and Replace function together in VBA

Tags: vba, csv, replace, find

I have a problem with an .CSV file.

Some of the values are prices with a comma to separate units and decimals, all the other fields are separated with a comma too.
So, as expected, it is impossible to convert my csv file like this. (If there is a way, please tell me)

Therefore, I am trying to write a **vba macro that will replace the comma by a dot**.

More specifically, I need to replace the 9th occurence of "," to a "." IF AND ONLY IF the character next to the comma respects a specific condition. That is why I need a macro to do so.

In excel, I was using the following formula to find the position of my comma:

`=Find(char(160),substitute(A2;",";char(160),9))`

This formula gives me the position of the 9th comma, that's perfect. I would like to know how to code this in VBA

Thanks in advance !

Alex

Comment: why?  What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: If I have the position of the comma, I can test if the next character corresponds to the decimals, or if it corresponds to the next field. In the first case, I need to replace the comma to a dot, in the other case, the comma needs to stay

Comment: to get the part after the 9th comma in vba, use `split` : `x = split(string,",")(9)`  This will return the data after the ninth comma.

Comment: so you can test the first character of the string: `If Left(split(string,",")(9),1) = "X" Then`

Comment: Oh very nice, thank you.
But now, how do I use the replace function to convert my comma to a dot ? I can't make it work like it does in an excel formula.
I mean, I still need the position of my comma right ?

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"),"," & split(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"),",")(9),"." & split(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"),",")(9))`

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's perfect

Comment: One more thing, When I use this line with Range("A2"), it works perfectly, but when I try to go through every line with Range("A" & i), it doesn't work anymore, it replaces all the commas of the cell by a dot.
Do you know why ?

Comment: no, sounds like a new question.  Please post a new question and include the smallest code needed to replicate the issue.  See [mcve].